# Find if an item exists in a json

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I'm trying to search for a ip in the JSON code useing nodejs request  .For Example if 127.0.0.1 is in the JSON code console.log('True') 
if not 127.0.0.1 in the JSON Code Console.Log('False)
i dont know what is the problem in my code !

```
const request = require('request')

request('http://localhost/checkdir.php?ips=1', function(error, res, body) {
    var ip = '127.0.0.1';
   var ips = JSON.parse(body);
    if(ips == ip.ip){
        console.log('FOUND 1 MATCH IP ID IS'.ip.id);
    }
})
```

the json code in http://localhost/checkdir.php?ips=1

is [{"id":"21","ip":"127.0.0.1},{"id":"22","ip":"127.0.0.2"}]

Comment: `if(ips == ip.ip)` why `ip.ip` ? it should be `if(ips[index].ip == ip)`. there are lots of typos in your code `console.log('FOUND 1 MATCH IP ID IS'.ip.id);` what is `.ip.it` and you need to seprate parameters in console by `,` not `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
request('http://localhost/checkdir.php?ips=1', function(error, res, body) {
   var ip = '127.0.0.1';
   var ips = JSON.parse(body);
   const match = ips.find(item => item.ip == ip);
   if (match) {
     console.log('FOUND 1 MATCH IP ID IS' + match.id);
   }
})
```

Comment: `ip.ip` is undefined

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of items and you just want to know if `some` condition is met, then you can use [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). It will return a boolean depending on whether or not the condition is met:

```js
let ips = [{"id":"21","ip":"127.0.0.1"},{"id":"22","ip":"127.0.0.2"}]

// true
console.log(ips.some(addr => addr.ip == "127.0.0.1"))
// false
console.log(ips.some(addr => addr.ip == "127.0.0.9"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use String search() method:

```
const request = require('request')

    request('http://localhost/checkdir.php?ips=1', function(error, res, body) {
        var ip = '127.0.0.1';
        var ips = JSON.parse(body);
        var n =  ips.search(ip);
        if(n != -1){
        console.log('FOUND 1 MATCH IP ID IS'.ip.id);
    }
})
```

The method returns -1 when there is no match. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp).

Comment: var n =  ips.search(ip);
                   ^

TypeError: ips.search is not a function

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
var obj =  [
{"id":"21","ip":"127.0.0.1"},
{"id":"22","ip":"127.0.0.2"}
];
var searchedIp = '127.0.0.1';
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  if (obj[i].ip == searchedIp){
  alert('true');
  return;
  }
}
alert('false');
```